# How to create desktop shortcut for msix packaged winui3 project

Tags: windows, winui-3, desktop-bridge

That is, after user installing the msix, there should be the shortcut. Or at least, the app create the shortcut after first launch. Not some post-installation script.

I tried [desktop7:Shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop7-shortcut), but the shortcut does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the packaged WinUI3 app cannot be started from the exe, so creating a shortcut is invalid, this is by design.

If you need to create a shortcut on the desktop, first you need to make your app non-packaged (unpackaged) and self-contained), you need to [modify your csproj file.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app#unpackaged-create-a-new-project-for-an-unpackaged-c-or-c-winui-3-desktop-app)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can try to [create a desktop shortcut with the Windows Script Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh).

**Project** > **Add Reference** > **COM** > **Windows Script Host Object Model**.

```
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hProcess, uint dwFlags,
                                                [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder lpExeName,
                                                ref uint lpdwSize);
private void CreateShortcut()
{
    // Get a handle to the current process
    IntPtr hProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
    uint dwFlags = 0;
    StringBuilder lpExeName = new StringBuilder(260);
    uint lpdwSize = (uint)lpExeName.Capacity;
    //Get exe path
    bool result = QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, dwFlags, lpExeName, ref lpdwSize);

    object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
    WshShell shell = new WshShell();
    string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\yourAppName.lnk";
    IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
    shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for a yourAppName";
    shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
    shortcut.TargetPath = lpExeName.ToString();
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a full-trust MSIX, you *should* be able to create a shortcut for it on first-run by using the Shell Folder APIs. To get started, take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/ptorr-msft/CreateAppShortcut) to see if it can work for you.

If it's a low-trust UWP then there is currently no solution.

Note that once you create the shortcut, **there is no way to automatically remove it when the MSIX app is uninstalled**; the shortcut will still be there but will just point to nothing.